# Is it possible to enrich the message payload data in the log4j2 HTTP appender?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I would like to add in more data to the message payload that is sent over in the http appender. Currently it is set to JSON format. My goal is to add in the app name to the message of each log4j message sent out.

Is it possible to enrich the message payload data in HTTP appender?

Here is my log4j2.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="MyApp">
  <Appenders>
    <Http name="Http" url="http://someserverlm.test" method="POST">
      <PatternLayout pattern="Appname=%c %msg"></PatternLayout>
      <Property name="X-Java-Runtime" value="$${java:runtime}" />
      <JsonLayout properties="true"/>

    </Http>

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Http" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Did you look at the successor of `JsonLayout`: [`JsonTemplateLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html)?

Comment: I have not, taking a look and will report back, thank you